# MainThread usage

Tags: c#, mobile, maui, platform-specific

I'm kinda new with the mobile app development, I've seen sometimes some snippets of async codes runned using `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, what's the difference beetween running some async code on `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` vs running some async code without it?

Is there some behaviour differences with the different platforms?

Answer (score 1):

UI can only be updated from the MAIN/UI thread.  Using [MainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/main-thread?view=net-maui-8.0) forces code that may be running on another thread to use the UI thread.